# Looking for a SIP soft phone for developers

Tags: debugging, testing, sip

I need a Windows SIP soft phone to test telephony applications. It should be developer-friendly. I must be able to see the log of all the SIP messages exchanged between peers. Ideally, it would allow starting more than one instance (on different ports) to simulate multiple agents in a call center.

I don't like X-Lite as it tries to hide the SIP protocol from the user .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing, the [KitCAT](http://echarts.org/KitCAT) framework is extremely (Java) developer-friendly. Test cases are written in JUnit, for ease of integration with other tools. It provides logs at varying levels (including SIP messages), and supports multiple user agents, which can all be coordinated within a test case. (The latter is not well supported in other SIP testing tools, such as [sipp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/)). It also provides coordination with other protocols (e.g., RTP, HTTP).

It's not a softphone in the traditional sense, but is tremendously helpful in the development process.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I also have a need for that.

Answer (score 1):

SIPp may do what you want.  http://sipp.sourceforge.net/

Its not a softphone, but does support multiple instances.  You can use Wireshark to see the log of all the SIP messages exchanged.